# Access denied exporting table from Google big query to bucket

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export a table to a bucket that I created and I am getting an access denied error. I tried looking at the bucket permissions but I dont quite get if I am the owner why am I being denied. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the destination bucket was created using the same project that is being used to send the export job to BigQuery. You could resolve permissions in a different way too, but since we don't have more details here, this will be the simplest.

Comment: I only have one project, anything else I should do?

Comment: Errors:Access Denied: Google Storage File gs://project/maximal-digit-836/storage/browser/coop_owner/: Access Denied